# Heroku black and white image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

i've push my files into heroku but somehow the output turn to be black and white. Why is this so ? What went wrong with it ? this is the link

http://rapd-primer-generator.herokuapp.com/

Comment: application.js and more importantly application.css aren't being found, you need to post more code around your asset pipeline etc.

Comment: how do i do that ? i thought when i put them into GitHub they will all be there ? Sorry just started learning deploying and it's my first time doing this.

Comment: it's cool :) Maybe try running `heroku run rake assets:precompile` from the command line and see what that does. It's hard to tell without any code but you probably just haven't precompiled

Comment: this is what i get back. ( only 2 lines of code ? )
`$ heroku run rake assets:precompile
Running `rake assets:precompile` attached to terminal... up, run.1148`

Comment: hmm that's alright. @BC2 you mentioned github, is this a public repo? If it is it'll be much easier to see whats going on

Comment: yes it's a public repo. here it is https://github.com/Spykids92/FYP

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43350/discussion-between-niall-and-bc2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the required Heroku gems, rails_12factor and it should look ok. Also, why are you using the RC of Rails4? Rails 4.0.2 is current.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#heroku-gems

Comment: what is RC ? btw how do i commit this update gemfile to my Github ?

Comment: The gem is quite simple - the gem brings in further gems and I suspect you're running into the scenario that serving static assets is disabled in production by default in Rails apps (check your production.rb) - the gem just changes that https://github.com/heroku/rails_serve_static_assets/blob/master/lib/rails_serve_static_assets/railtie.rb

Comment: https://github.com/Spykids92/FYP/blob/master/config/environments/production.rb#L23 - you could just set this to true and not need the gem but it's advisable as it does changes around logging too.

Comment: ic. It works ok now however my signing in is giving me error n i don't know what's going on with it. IT works fine in localhost but now it's werird